A bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Q}^+$
I found a nice problem and I would like some help :

Let $f$ a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Q}^+$ such that :
i) $f(0) = 0$
ii) $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f(2n+1) = \displaystyle\frac{1}{f(n)+1}$
iii) $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, $f(2n) = f(n)+1$

1. Find $f(n)$ for all $n \in [\![ 0,8 ]\!]$.
2. Show that $f$ is injective.
3. Find $n$ such that $f(n) = \frac{14}{5}$.
4. Show that $f$ is surjective.

My attempt :
1. We have :
$f(0)=0$; $f(1)=1$; $f(2)=2$; $f(3)=\frac{1}{2}$; $f(4)=3$; $f(5)=\frac{1}{3}$; $f(6)=\frac{3}{2}$; $f(7)=\frac{2}{3}$; $f(8)=4$
2. We first see that : $$\forall m,n \in \mathbb{N}^*, \hspace{0,1cm} f(2m+1) < 1 < f(2n) $$
Let $p,q \in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that $f(p)=f(q)$. We'll show that $p=q$.
By the inequality above, $p$ and $q$ have same parity.
$\bullet$ If $p,q$ are even numbers, then $f(\frac{p}{2}) = f(\frac{q}{2})$.
$\bullet$ If $p,q$ are odd numbers, then $f(\frac{p-1}{2}) = f(\frac{q-1}{2})$.
Let $p'=\frac{p}{2}$ (resp. $q' = \frac{q}{2}$) if $p,q$ were even, or let $p'=\frac{p-1}{2}$ (resp. $q' = \frac{q-1}{2}$) if $p,q$ were odd. We reiterate this process a finite number of time and we must obtain $0=0$. Hence $p=q$ and $f$ is injective.
3. We have $f(9) = \frac{1}{4}$. So $f(18) = 1+\frac{1}{4} = \frac{5}{4}$, and then $f(19) = \frac{4}{5}$, so $f(38) = 1+\frac{4}{5} = \frac{9}{5}$, thus $f(76) = 1 + \frac{9}{5} = \frac{14}{5}$.
4. I don't see any patern. We can observe that : $$\forall k \in \mathbb{N}^*, \hspace{0.1cm} f(2^{k-1}) = k$$
I'm kinda lost here, I would love to do some binary (like in the Stern–Brocot tree). All I can say right now is that we can obtain :
$\bullet$ Every natural numbers.
$\bullet$ Every inverse of natural numbers.
Let $\frac{p}{q}\in \mathbb{Q}^+$. By euclidean division we can find $k,r$ such that $p=kq+r$. Thus : $$\frac{p}{q} = k + \frac{r}{q}, \hspace{0.4cm} 0 \leqslant r < q$$
It is then maybe sufficient to show that we can obtain every rationals in $\left\{ \frac{1}{q}, \dots, \frac{q-1}{q} \right\}$.
Because apparently (I can't prove it) we have : $$\forall n,k \in \mathbb{N}^*, f(2^{k-1}n) = (k-1) + f(n)$$

Where is the part of the proof where you establish $\forall m,n \in \mathbb{N}^*, \hspace{0,1cm} f(2m+1) < 1 < f(2n)$?

Your last formula is easy to prove (by induction on $k$).

You can use the continued fraction expansion for rationals to show 4.

@jjagmath Let $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$. You have $f(2n) = f(n) + 1 > 1$ because $f(n)>0$. Moreover, you have $f(2n+1) = \frac{1}{f(n)+1} < 1$ (again because $f(n)>0$).

@JoshuaTilley Amazing! Won't you post an answer?

Let us prove by induction on $n$ that for every $n\in\Bbb N$, the range of $f$ contains every positive fraction $\frac pq$ with denominator $q\le n$.
You already proved the base case $n=1$. Assume now that the claim holds for $n$ and let us prove it for $n+1$, i.e. let us prove that the range of $f$ contains every positive fraction $\frac m{n+1}$. By Euclidean division, let $$\frac m{n+1}=a+\frac b{n+1},\quad0\le b\le n.$$
By induction hypothesis, $$\frac{n+1-b}b=f(x)$$ for some $x$, so that $\frac b{n+1}=f(2x+1),$ and
$$\frac m{n+1}=f(2^a(2x+1)).$$

That's great. Thanks Anne. The induction predicate is $P_n$ : $f(\mathbb{N})$ contains every positive rational numbers $\frac{p}{q}$ such that $q \leqslant n$ ?
Also why "strong" induction when we only use $P_n$ in heredity ?

You are completely right. I thought strong induction on $q$, but wrote it as a simple induction on $n$.

We use continued fractions as more formal way of talking about Euclidean Division
We can represent any rational number as a finite continued fraction $p=[a_0;a_1;a_2\cdots;a_n]$
So by definition
$$
p=a_o+\frac1{a_1+\frac1{a_2+\frac1{a_3+\cdots}}}
$$
For smaller values of $n$ for example $p=[a_0;a_1;a_2]$
We have $$f(2^{a_0}(2^{a_1}(2^{a_2-1}+1)+1))=p$$
Can generalize this to larger values of $n$

Oh indeed ! Great ! For example $\frac{14}{5} = [2,1,4]$ and $2^2(2^1(2^{4-1}+1) +1) = 4 \times 19 = 76$. That's stunning.

Yes (+1), great @JoshuaTilley's idea.

So you have everything except #4 (which I do think is the hardest part).  You want to look at how you did #3 and show that this can be applied to any positive rational number (not just $ 1 4 / 5 $).  You didn't really show how you got your answer to #3 (I mean how you knew to start with $ f ( 9 ) $), but if I look at it backwards, I can figure it out:

Since $ 1 4 / 5 > 1 $, you know that it comes from an even number, so you look at $ 1 4 / 5 - 1 $, which is $ 9 / 5 $.
Since $ 9 / 5 > 1 $, you know that it too comes from an even number, so you look at $ 9 / 5 - 1 $, which is $ 4 / 5 $.
Since $ 4 / 5 < 1 $, you know that it now comes from an odd number, so you look at $ 1 / ( 4 / 5 ) - 1 $, which is $ 1 / 4 $.
Now you have the reciprocal of an integer, which you know can always be done.

So you just have to argue that you can apply this process to any positive rational number and always work your way back to an integer or its reciprocal.  Actually I think that it's cleaner if you go further than that: you can always work your way back to $ 1 / 1 $.
You can prove this similarly to #2, that there's some natural number getting smaller at each stage, so that the process can't continue forever.  In #2, it's your $ p $ and $ q $ that are always getting smaller (until you reach $ 0 $, where it must stop).  Here you have a rational number that's always getting smaller, but that's no help; but if you look at the numerators and denominators, then you should see that some natural number is always getting smaller (until you reach somewhere where it must stop).

Since other answers are beyond hints, I may as well spell out the end of my answer: the maximum of the numerator and denominator is always getting smaller, and so will eventually reach $ 1 $ (at which point the number is $ 1 / 1$).
